# How to keep a local object not be GCed in c#?

Tags: garbage-collection

I have this method:

```
private static void StartLicensePlateMonitor(Autofac.IContainer container)
    {

        var monitor = container.Resolve<LicensePlate.LicensePlateUploadMonitor>();
        monitor.Start();

        System.GC.KeepAlive(monitor); //does this work?

    }
```

I want to keep monitor alive all time until program shut down, does the statement "System.GC.KeepAlive(monitor);" work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The documentation for [`System.GC.KeepAlive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) says that it ensures that the argument is alive *up until the call to `KeepAlive()`*. It's just a dummy function that the GC promises to not check for actual uses of the argument.

If you want an object to stay alive, ensure there is always a reference to it. It should be sufficient to store it in a `private static` field. If you have an arbitrary number of them, then store it in a `List` in a field.